# laravel 9 + Vue.js 2 And Vite im facing error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, vuejs2, vite, laravel-9

I'm new in laravel 9 and vite my old project im using laravel 7 with laravel/UI vue.js 2 for my project now im using laravel 9 and vue.js 2 and vite for my project im developed as my old style in used in laravel 7 , but im facing some error IN LARAVEL 9 WITH VITE.
ERROR

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'id')

**MY PROJECT CODE**
**APP.VUE**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import {Vue} from "vue";
import router from "./router";

window.Vue = require('vue');
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
});
```

**ROUTER**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

// MainComponents
  import Home from "./components/MainComponents/Home.vue";
 
  
const routes = [
    //Admin Login
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
    },
  
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: "history",
});

export default router;
```

**WELCOME.BLADE.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HELLO</title>

    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>
</html>
```

**WEB.PHP**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**COMPONENT**

```
<template>
       <div >
                       MAIN PAGE COMPONENT                         
       </div> 
</template>
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Try changing `vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',` to `vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',`

Answer (score -3):

First things first, it is not really practical to use `require` in vite project, but if you do, you have to either use a plugin or manually work around it. Does the id error comes from the vite file itself or from your code?

Comment: is there any solution for this I'm also facing same issues